# What is the number of one-to-one functions from the set $\{1, 2,\dots , n\}$ to the set $\{1, 2, \dots , 2n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

What is the number of one-to-one functions from the set $\{1, 2,\dots , n\}$ to the set $\{1, 2, \dots , 2n\}$ so that $2i − 1$ and $2i$ on the right-hand set are not mapped at the same time for all $1 \leq i \leq n$?

So, I know that between a set with $n$ elements and a set with $m$ elements there will be $n!$ one-to-one functions.

I don't know how to expand that on to this question. If you could explain the steps to solving this problem I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean $n$ rather than $m$?

Comment: And by "are not mapped at the same time for all $1 \le i \le n$" do you mean "are not both in the range of the function"?

Comment: You wrote "between a set with $n$ elements and a set with $m$ elements".  You meant "between a set with $n$ elements and a set with $n$ elements".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the number of one-to-one functions in the following problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147407/what-is-the-number-of-one-to-one-functions-in-the-following-problem)

Comment: The answer in the linked question is incorrect.  The answer provided here is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a one-to-one function $f$ from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,2n\}$ such that the range does not include both $2i-1$ and $2i$ for any $i$, first choose for each $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ which of $2i-1$ and $2i$ should be in the range.  That can be done in $2^n$ ways.  Then map $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to 
your $n$ choices, which can be done in $n!$ ways.  So the answer is $2^n \; n!$.

Comment: So for you answer, it does not include 2i-1 and 2i for any i, but doesn't the question ask for them not to be mapped at the same time? Or am i misunderstanding the question?

Comment: As clarified in comments (since deleted), this is what was meant by "not mapped at the same time".